# How to navigate through links in differents levels selenium vba

Tags: vba, selenium

Actually, im trying to navigate to a block that has 3 levels.

- First level im clicking to open the tree
- Second level is an category with Href
- Third level sometimes has subcategory with href too

So im trying to navigate through second and third level if exists.

My code works fine at level 1, it clicks all the items from level 1, but for the second level is not working properly.

What can be wrong at second level and how I can do to reach the third one?

[image: Image example]

```html
driver.Get "https://www.tecnoglobal.cl/tiendaonline/webapp/ofertas/"
                    
driver.Window.Maximize
                    
Set categories = driver.FindElementsByXPath(".//*[@id='acordeon-productos-subcat']")
                    
driver.FindElementByXPath(".//*[@id='js-productos']").Click
                    
For Each category In categories
                
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")           
category.FindElementByXPath("ancestor::div/a/span").Click
                        
Set categorylinks = driver.FindElementsByXPath(".//*[@id='acordeon-productos-subcat']")
                        
For Each categorylink In categorylinks
                        
linkcategory = categorylink.FindElementByXPath("descendant::div/descendant::span").Text
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links are already present on page load so you don't need to click on products or navigate through tree. Simply gather an initial collection of the final nodes using a css [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector based on the `ng-if` attribute value. From that webElements collection extract the href attributes into an array, loop that array and .Get to each one.

Saving the links into an array avoids stale elements exceptions/element not found bubbling up when you navigate away from source page.

There are two patterns specified with Or "," syntax so as to match on 2nd `Subcategoria` and 3rd `Subsubcategorias` links.

---

```
Dim targets As WebElements, links(), link As webElement, i As Long

Set targets = driver.FindElementsByCss("[ng-if='!Subcategoria.leaf'],[ng-if='!Subsubcategorias.leaf']")
ReDim links(1 To targets.Count)

For Each link In targets
    i = i + 1
    links(i) = link.Attribute("href")
Next
For i = LBound(links) To UBound(links)
    driver.Get links(i)
    'do something on page
Next
```

Comment: Wow, I just was clicking on each category level 1 because before your code it says something like "the element is not visible". Now, it works with your code, but I just erase this part:

For i = LBound(links) To UBound(links)

Next

Because what I do inside the page when it finish, it is not capable to get the another new link and then do something inside it, the "next" just enter out of the links(i) = link.Attribute("href") and it gives me error "argument url cannot be null"

Why is important that part of lbound and ubound?

Comment: I just read the code step by step, amazing, you first go to read all the links, and then store it in some kind of memory then go to every link 1 by 1, awesome, Thanks you very much, now I understand why the lbound and ubound was important.